# Merge Unique Rows in PowerShell DataTable

Tags: powershell, datatable

I have a script that contains two similar queries from different servers. They contain the same columns, and I stored them in a DataTable.

So I have *$myDataTable1* and *$myDataTable2*, both with the same 3 columns. I would like to **MERGE** the two tables **ONLY FOR** **distinct** rows.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried $myDataTable1.merge($myDataTable2) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the datatables and use `DataView`'s `ToTable(bool distinct, params string[] columns)`-method to filter out distinct values only. Ex:

```
$dt1 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dt1.Columns.Add("Make") > $null
$dt1.Columns.Add("Model") > $null
$dt1.Columns.Add("Year") > $null
$dt1.Rows.Add("Ford","Mustang","2010") > $null
$dt1.Rows.Add("Ford","Mustang","2011") > $null
$dt1.Rows.Add("VW","Golf","2016") > $null

$dt2 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dt2.Columns.Add("Make") > $null
$dt2.Columns.Add("Model") > $null
$dt2.Columns.Add("Year") > $null
$dt2.Rows.Add("Ford","Fiesta","2010") > $null
$dt2.Rows.Add("Ford","Mustang","2011") > $null
$dt2.Rows.Add("VW","Golf","2016") > $null

#Load $dt2-values into $dt1
$dt1.Merge($dt2)

#Show merged table
$dt1

Make Model   Year
---- -----   ----
Ford Mustang 2010
Ford Mustang 2011
VW   Golf    2016
Ford Fiesta  2010
Ford Mustang 2011
VW   Golf    2016

#Get distinct values only (distinct rows for make, model and year)
$dt1.DefaultView.ToTable($true,"Make","Model","Year")

Make Model   Year
---- -----   ----
Ford Mustang 2010
Ford Mustang 2011
VW   Golf    2016
Ford Fiesta  2010
```